# Where to ask question when SO has tag but question seems off-topic?

Tags: support, tags, site-recommendation

I have a question about JasperSoft ReportsServer Authentication Priorities and although it seems it´s a better at "Server Fault" there is no such tag like "JasperSoft" at all. On "Stack Overflow" on the other hand, there is (probably because most people use this site).

Should I post it on SO where I´ll probably get an answer quickly but might get flagged as off-topic (which is basically right) or post it on in another site where I can´t even tag it. Or is there any other Stack Exchange site where this might fit in better?

---

After somebody marked this as a duplicate I want to clarify my question and show why it is not a duplicate of the other post:

It doesn't really belong on SO because it´s not a coding problem, it certainly doesn't belong on software engineering as it has nothing to do with engineering. I didn't know about Database Administrators (so thanks for that) but this doesn't seem right either because it is mainly the authentication of this server software and not the databases but it is not really IT Security because the security part is already taken care of, my problem is just the configuration.

So I guess my question (a bit rephrased) is:

Is it bad practice to post in a site where the post seems off-topic but there is already a tag and questions along the way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the post but my question wasn´t really answered there so I updated it.

Comment: The presence of a tag on any SE site does not imply the subject matter is on topic. I can create a "diamondback" tag on SO, but herpetology is still not on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say DO NOT post to a site where you know your question would be off-topic.

If you believe your question will be on-topic at a site where it does not have the tag you are looking for then post it there without that tag and visit the Meta of that site to ask to have it added.

If you really are not sure whether your question will be on-topic at a site, even after reviewing its help, then consider posting in that site's Meta to ask if it is.